# Divs have different heights, where are they inheriting their heights from?

Tags: javascript, html, css, inheritance, flexbox

I am trying to display made up stores using cards. I'm setting a max width so that the images will keep their aspect ratio, unequal card sizes are expected. I'm grouping these cards inside of a flex container so that I don't have to worry about their placement in the page too much. However, when I do this, I get equal size cards. The images are different sizes and keep their aspect ratio which is good, but the body of the cards change to whatever will make the cards equal size.

I am trying to understand why this happens. What is it about the flex container that makes the elements inside of it be of equal size? I apologize if it's a dumb question but I couldn't figure it out. Note that this is only visible when looking at the page horizontally. The size of the cards is actually how I want it to be when looking at it vertically.

```css
/* Set HTML and Body width and height properties to 100% so other elements can use the % property */
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #557d79ff;
    /* f37970 */
}

/* Define the main Navigation block */
.myNav {
    display: flex;
    height: 3.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.6;
    /* background-color: #e6a69c; */
    background-color: #FC766AFF;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
/* Remove bullets, margin and padding */
.myNav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Sansita Swashed', cursive;
}
.myNav li {
    float: left;
    /* Or you can use display: inline; */
}
/* Define the block styling for the links */
.myNav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    color: white;
}
/* This is optional, however if you want to display the active link differently apply a background to it */
.myNav li a.active {
    background-color: #557d79ff;
}

/**********************************  CARD SECTION START  **********************************/

/* Cards container */
.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background-color: white;
}

/* Card Body */
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 5rem 5rem 5rem 5rem; /* 5px rounded corners */
    width: 20rem;
    background-color: #c9d4ceFF;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    /* height: 100%; */
}

/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
  
/* Add some padding inside the card container */
.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    border-radius: 0rem 0rem 5rem 5rem;
}
 
/* Add rounded corners to the top left and the top right corner of the image */
img {
    /* border-radius: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem; */
    margin-top: 0rem;
    border-radius: 5rem 5rem 0rem 0rem;
    max-width: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Google Fonts! -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sansita+Swashed:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome! -->
    <script defer src="all.js"></script>
    <title>Cards & Navbar</title>
    <!-- Custom CSS! -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- NAVBAR START -->
    <nav class="myNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-mug-hot"></i> Find Me Food Now!</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- END NAVBAR -->

    <!-- CARDS START -->

    <!-- FLEX CARDS -->
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ItaV89TNkks" alt="Avatar">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <h3><b>Best Cafe</b></h3>
                <h4>Jonathan</h4>
                <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/d5SZqLkpIrY" alt="Avatar">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <h3><b>Best Cafe</b></h3>
                <h4>Jonathan</h4>
                <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the div is stretched, not inherited.

The default 'align-items' of 'display:flex' is 'stretch', so it will stretch to the height of the largest axis.

To get the look you want, you need to change the 'align-items' to one of the following: 'baseline, center, flex-start, flex-end'.

```css
/* Set HTML and Body width and height properties to 100% so other elements can use the % property */
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #557d79ff;
    /* f37970 */
}

/* Define the main Navigation block */
.myNav {
    display: flex;
    height: 3.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.6;
    /* background-color: #e6a69c; */
    background-color: #FC766AFF;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
/* Remove bullets, margin and padding */
.myNav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Sansita Swashed', cursive;
}
.myNav li {
    float: left;
    /* Or you can use display: inline; */
}
/* Define the block styling for the links */
.myNav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    color: white;
}
/* This is optional, however if you want to display the active link differently apply a background to it */
.myNav li a.active {
    background-color: #557d79ff;
}

/**********************************  CARD SECTION START  **********************************/

/* Cards container */
.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background-color: white;
    align-items: baseline;
}

/* Card Body */
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 5rem 5rem 5rem 5rem; /* 5px rounded corners */
    width: 20rem;
    background-color: #c9d4ceFF;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    /* height: 100%; */
}

/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
  
/* Add some padding inside the card container */
.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    border-radius: 0rem 0rem 5rem 5rem;
}
 
/* Add rounded corners to the top left and the top right corner of the image */
img {
    /* border-radius: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem; */
    margin-top: 0rem;
    border-radius: 5rem 5rem 0rem 0rem;
    max-width: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Google Fonts! -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sansita+Swashed:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome! -->
    <script defer src="all.js"></script>
    <title>Cards & Navbar</title>
    <!-- Custom CSS! -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- NAVBAR START -->
    <nav class="myNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-mug-hot"></i> Find Me Food Now!</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- END NAVBAR -->

    <!-- CARDS START -->

    <!-- FLEX CARDS -->
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ItaV89TNkks" alt="Avatar">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <h3><b>Best Cafe</b></h3>
                <h4>Jonathan</h4>
                <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/d5SZqLkpIrY" alt="Avatar">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <h3><b>Best Cafe</b></h3>
                <h4>Jonathan</h4>
                <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense, thank you so much! That was a lot more simple than I thought it would be haha